# What should be the correct return value of a pure virtual function in .cpp file?

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ and have a basic question. My program has a header file and a .cpp one as well. In the header file there are two functions:

```cpp
int getSize() const = 0;
string getName() const = 0;
```

and in the corresponding part of the .cpp file:

```cpp
int Class1::getSize() const { return 0;};
string Class1::getName() const {return "";};
```

What should I use inside the body of each function in .cpp file? As these two functions are overwritten in the derived classes, can I put anything in the body of the classes in the .cpp file? for example can I leave their bodies empty? (although I receive warning messages) or use null for string or any other values for each. I am looking for a standard and correct way of doing it.
Thanks.

Comment: Your  methods `pure virtual`. That is, the body is optional. You seem to have some bodies, but you can retain them or just delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pure virtual functions, you can omit the definition altogether. There are exceptions, when you must give a definition:

- pure virtual destructors (because destructors of derived classes will call it)
- if you call a pure virtual function (for example, from a function of a derived class)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My code has a pure virtual destructor and also those two pure virtual function that I mentioned in the question are called in the derived classes. Therefore, according to your answer I should keep their bodies but my question is what should be the contents of the bodies?

Comment: @Coder: what's the reason that you call them in derived classes?

Comment: Each derived class instance has its own size and name.

Comment: @Coder: But why do you call a function of the base class in derived classes? For having an own name/size, this is not needed.

Comment: You are right, even without these functions in the base class, the program runs well but this is a coursework that's why I am not sure whether to keep them or not. Basically the template was given and the functions bodies are supposed to be filled.

Comment: @Coder: most of the time, pure virtual functions don't have a definition. If it doesn't make any sense to give an implementation, then don't give it. The problem statement should be clear on this. Looking at this problem in a different angle: if you call `Base::getName()` from `Derived::getName()`, what do you do with the returned value? Or you just call `Base::getName()`, and then ignore the return value of it?

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Just one more question about the destructors, when we have a pure virtual destructor in the base class, do we need to give any definition to the derived classes destructors?

Comment: It is not mandatory. If you don't declare the destructor, the compiler will generate one.